# Sorting list of lists by 3rd, 2nd, 1st element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list of lists like:

```
[[5, 8, 12], [6, 8, 10], [9, 20, 31], [14, 16, 13],...,[19,9,44]]
```

How can I sort this (preferably in Python) in increasing order by the 3rd element in each subarray, then by the 2nd element in eacy subarray then by first?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sorted` with `itemgetter` in the `key` argument to fetch the items in reverse order:

```
from operator import itemgetter
l = [[5, 8, 12], [6, 8, 10], [9, 20, 31], [14, 16, 13],[19,9,44]]

sorted(l, key=itemgetter(2,1,0))
# [[6, 8, 10], [5, 8, 12], [14, 16, 13], [9, 20, 31], [19, 9, 44]]
```

Or using a lambda function:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[::-1])
# [[6, 8, 10], [5, 8, 12], [14, 16, 13], [9, 20, 31], [19, 9, 44]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a key-function that retrieves the 3rd element from each sub-list & use that.

```
l = [[5, 8, 12], [6, 8, 10], [9, 20, 31], [14, 16, 13],...,[19,9,44]]
l.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])
```

Or you can use `itemgetter`